# How to synchronize view component data with a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, view-components

I want to display my .NET Core web page as per the below image.

[image]

For the left pane, I am using a partial view whereas I'm rendering the right pane with view components.

I call different API's to retrieve data from the database in order to display data in both panes.

I want to synchronize the left pane record count with right pane view component data.

Is their any pattern/combination of view components or partial views to achieve my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to synchronize left pane record count with right pane view components data. Is their any pattern/combination of view-components or partial views to synchronize my requirement.

You can put rows of each view component into specific "container" with specific css class, such as "vc1-row",  "vc2-row" etc.

On client side, you can traverse rows of view component(s) and calculate count of rows of each view component after DOM is ready, and update/repopulate left panel record count via JavaScript/jQuery code.

Besides, if you'd like to implement something like portal/dashboard, which could retrieve data from back-end service and push real-time data to clients and update clients UI with new data, you can try to use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1).